# List of values jump cells to find the least expensive route (incorrect output)

Tags: python, list, recursion, logic, calculation

I have a program that is supposed to play the game of Jump it. I am given values and have to recursively move through the values in the least expensive way. I can either jump to the adjacent cell or jump two over to that cell. My program is as follows:

```
def jumpIt(n, k, lst):
    sums = []
    #sums will collect the 'cost' of the game in a list
    if (k > n-1):
        #first base case if the list if the length is 0
        return 0
    elif (k+1 > n-1):
        #2nd base case if the list is two cells
        return lst[k]
    else: 
        if (lst[k] < lst[k+1]):
            sums.append(lst[k])
            #if the cell of K is less than k+1 computes:
            return lst[k] + jumpIt(n, k+2, lst) 
        else:
            sums.append(lst[k+1])
            return lst[k+1] + jumpIt(n, k+2, lst)



def main(): 
    #list to sum the cost of each move 
    fileName = "input.txt"
    for line in open(fileName):
        lst = line.split()
        lst = [int(x) for x in lst]
        print(jumpIt(len(lst),1,lst))

main()
```

the input is as

```
0 3 80 6 57 10
0 98 7 44 25 3 5 85 46 4
0 57 59 83 9 42 70
0 20 49 96 53 7 43 77
0 24 17 15 61 49 8 65 43 26 99 7 57 97 50 93 6 82 52
```

and the correct output is suppose to be:

```
19
87
138
186
330
```

However with my given code the output I am receiving is

```
19
85
108
157
224
```

I have no idea why it is doing this could anyone help?

Comment: Hi, how do you suppose to calculate the output?

Comment: that is what I am not sure about. I thought if i put all the moves in a list and used the sum function to sum them that would display the correct output, but I am not entirely sure how to do so. @Arief

Comment: I meant, how dou you calculate the output manually..?

Comment: lets say you have a list of

Comment: 0 98 7 44 25 3 5 85 46 4 the goal is starting at 0 a play must move through the list in the least expensive move by either jumping to the adjacent cell or two cells over so for this list the answer is 7 + 25 + 5 + 46 + 4 meaning the cost would be 87 @Arief

Comment: Correct output on last one is 327 not 330.

Comment: @גלעדברקן how did you come to that answer?

Comment: `sum [0, 17, 61, 8, 43, 26, 7, 57, 50, 6, 52]`

Comment: I thinks the 2nd one should be : 7 + 25 + 3 + 5 + 46 + 4

Comment: How do you calculate the output manually and what's the reason..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your program is returning what it does. Perhaps you could log step by step and see what's going on - a good candidate might be the short sequence `0 57 59 83 9 42 70` where you could see where the answer diverges from the expected output. Each cell is reached from one or two steps behind so if we "knew" which one was best ahead of time we could pick that one. Luckily, we can go go back in time using recursion:

```py
def f(lst):
  def g(i):
    if i < 0:
      return 0
    return lst[i] + min(g(i-1), g(i-2))

  return g(len(lst) - 1)

print f([0, 24, 17, 15, 61, 49, 8, 65, 43, 26, 99, 7, 57, 97, 50, 93, 6, 82, 52])
# 327 => sum [0, 17, 61, 8, 43, 26, 7, 57, 50, 6, 52]
```